# MATLAB, Nested For Loop Not Working on Second Iteration

Tags: matlab, for-loop, nested-loops

I have code that looks like this:

```
clc; close all; clear all;
k = 10; N = 50; f = 0.1; b = round(f*N);
for x = 1:2
    R = []; W = zeros(N,N); rand_vec = [];
    for i = 1:k+1
        rand_vec = [ones(b,1); zeros(N-b,1)];
        rand_vec = rand_vec(randperm(N));
        T(:,i) = rand_vec;
    end
    for c = 1:k
        for r = 1:N
            if T(r,c+1) == 1
                ones = find(T(:,c));
                W(ones,r) = W(ones,r) + 1;
            end
        end
        W(find(W)) = 1;
    end
    for j = 1:k
        RVT = T';
        R = [R; RVT(j,:)*W];
    end
    R(find(R<5)) = 0;
    R(find(R>=5)) = 1;
    E = sum(length(find(R))-length(find(RVT(2:11,:))));
end
```

Everything within the outer for loop with the variable x works fine for the first run through.  On the second iteration of the for loop, I get the following error message:

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

```
Error in Untitled4 (line 7)
        rand_vec = rand_vec(randperm(N));
```

I'm not really sure how to resolve this issue.  When I set x == 1, the code works fine.  That section of the code is supposed to generate a matrix (N by k+1) containing randomly spaced 0s and 1s with frequency (f).

Comment: The `rand_vect` is somehow generated to be `[46x1]` and `randperm[N]` is of `[1x50]` thus obviously you cannot access 47 and upward indexes of `rand_vect` by `randperm(N)`

Comment: @adil, in the line above I wrote a statement that I believe generates a 50 x 1 vector called rand_vec.  Am I misinterpreting what I intended to write?  The code works when I remove the loop variable x or set it equal to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this line, I believe:

```
ones = find(T(:,c));
```

You are overwriting the MATLAB function `ones` with a variable. This means that the statement `ones(b,1)` will be evaluated as `variable(5,1)`, which will just grab the 5th element of your `ones` variable, instead of generating a vector of ones.

There are (at least) two possible solutions:

1. Rename your `ones` variable.
2. At the end of your `x`-loop, add in a line `clear ones`.